# Monodevelop does not show the contents of the UnityEngine namespace in the autocomplete popup, but the scripts are still working properly. Why?

Tags: unity, c#, monodevelop

This is not the first time when I use Monodevelop for script editing it shows all UnityEngine related stuff in the autocomplete popup and than it randomly decides not to do so.

Reopening it didn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: The scripts will work because Unity compiles them, your issue appears to be with the editor not working properly. Did you try reinstalling it?

Comment: I had this problem recently when using a project mapped on a network share. It also generated an error in the Unity editor about an invalid URI. Does that match your situation?

Answer (score 1):

is a typical problem of Monodevelop and Unity.

Close it and double click on a Script from Unity, that opens it correctly.

Do not open it from Monodevelop access.

Or another way is, from the solution explorer in Monodevelop, right click and reload.